# XmlWriter only escaping one kind of quote

Tags: c#, escaping, xmlwriter

Here's some C# code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var w = XmlWriter.Create(sb);
w.WriteStartElement("hello");
w.WriteAttributeString("target", "world ' \" !");
w.WriteEndElement();
w.Flush();
// then look at sb.ToString()
```

I'm getting a string that looks like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><hello target="world ' &quot; !" />
```

It's only escaping the double-quote, not the single-quote.  But the docs for XmlWriter.WriteAttributeString(String, String) say:

> If the attribute value includes double or single quotes, they are
>   replaced with &quot; and &apos; respectively.

Is there some flag I need to set to make it do what the docs say it does?

Comment: As they're semantically the same, can you explain why this is causing you issues?

Comment: Compatibility with legacy systems, sadly.  Admittedly it wouldn't be a problem if it and .NET's XmlWriter didn't appear to have overlapping bugs.  :P

Comment: So the legacy system can't understand valid XML. Ick.

Comment: *shrug*  And .NET's WriteAttributeString doesn't obey even the first sentence of its docstring.  If I wanted to just pass blame for bad systems I have to work with, I could do that all day long.  :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use .Net Reflector to look at the code, you'll find that the System.Xml.XmlTextEncoder.Write(string) method is being called.  Here's the code of interest:

```
if (!this.inAttribute || (this.quoteChar != ch))
   this.textWriter.Write('\'');
else
   this.WriteEntityRefImpl("apos");
```

When writing an attribute value, a single quote is not escaped since it doesn't need to be.  It's only when writing a text element that "&apos;" is used.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a bug in the `XmlWriter`, it's a bug in your legacy system.

If you look at the definition of `AttValue` in the XML 1.0 recommendation, you'll see that the `XmlWriter` is doing exactly what it's supposed to be doing:  if the attribute value is delimited with apostrophes, an attribute value can contain quotation marks, and if it's delimited with quotation marks, an attribute value can contain apostrophes.

You could, conceivably, derive a class from `XmlTextWriter` and override its `WriteAttributes` and `WriteAttributeString` methods.  That might work.  Watch out for namespaces and encoding if you do this, though.

Comment: When the official docs say a method should do something, and it doesn't, I call that a bug.  YMMV.  :-)

Comment: Sure, but that's a bug in the docs.  They're trying to be too helpful.  What the docs *ought* to note is implementation-specific behavior, e.g. the fact that the method escapes > even though the XML recommendation doesn't require it.